# modifying a sliding javascript div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I got some code off the net to make a box slide in. However it slid in from the top left and I wanted it to slide in from the bottom. I changed the css position from top:-200px to bottom:-200px and changed the part of the code that alters the position from

```
{
    popup.style.top = (currentTop + speed) + "px";
    keepMoving = true;
}
```

to

```
{
    popup.style.bottom = (currentTop + speed) + "px";
    keepMoving = true;
}
```

now it doesn't work. I cannot see what variable I should be making. Here is the full code (which works if I change them back to 'top')

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Moving Pop Up Samplet</title>


<style>

#popup 
{
height:200px; 
width:200px; 
border:1px solid #000; 
background:#CC9900;
position:absolute;
bottom:-200px;
left:-200px;
}

</style>


<script>

var timer = null;
var speed = 3; //1 is  slow
var endTop = 0;
var endLeft = 0;

//******************************************************
// Simple little function to get Elements as an object
//******************************************************
function getEl(id)
{
var el = document.getElementById(id);
return el;
}
//******************************************************
// Function to show Elements
//******************************************************
function showEl(id)
{
getEl(id).style.display ="";
 }
   //******************************************************
  // Function to hide Elements
     //******************************************************
   function hideEl(id)
 {
getEl(id).style.display ="none";
  }

   //******************************************************
   // Function to move Element
     //******************************************************
    function moveEl(id)
    {
var popup = getEl(id);
var currentTop = parseInt(popup.offsetTop);
var currentLeft = parseInt(popup.offsetLeft);

var keepMoving = false;
//Move
if (currentTop <= endTop)
{
    popup.style.bottom = (currentTop + speed) + "px";
    keepMoving = true;
}
if(currentLeft <= endLeft)
{   
    popup.style.left = (currentLeft + speed) + "px";
    keepMoving = true;
}
if (keepMoving)
{
    startMove(id);
}
else
{
    endMove();
}
  }
   //******************************************************
   // Function to start the move
      //******************************************************
     function startMove(id)
    {
timer = setTimeout("moveEl('"+id+"')", 1);
   }
  //******************************************************
    // Function to end the move
 //******************************************************
  function endMove()
{
clearTimeout(timer);
 }

 </script>

</head>
<body onload="startMove('popup');">
<!-- POP UP DIV -->
<div id="popup">
<center><span onclick="hideEl('popup');" style="cursor:pointer;"> Close</span></center>
</div>
<!--END  POP UP DIV -->

<center><span onclick="startMove('popup');" style="cursor:pointer;"> Show Pop Up</span></center>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i wish things where so easy...

Comment: i figured that was the case, i suspect an answer as to why I can't do that would be just as long. ho hum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just need to rejiggle your inequalities a bit.

Given that there's no offset bottom property in javascript, it'll be easier to still work with top values, even if you want to come in from the bottom.

```
function moveEl(id) {
    var popup = getEl(id);

    var currentTop = parseInt(popup.offsetTop);
    var currentLeft = parseInt(popup.offsetLeft);

    var keepMoving = false;
    //Move
    if (currentTop >= endTop) {
        popup.style.top = (currentTop - speed) + "px";
        keepMoving = true;
    }
    if (currentLeft <= endLeft) {
        popup.style.left = (currentLeft + speed) + "px";
        keepMoving = true;
    }
    if (keepMoving) {
        startMove(id);
    }
    else {
        endMove();
    }
}
```

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFafk/).

If you think about the way the function is checking to see if it's finished yet, and adding on the `speed` variable each time, you should be able to step through the original version compared to this and see how the logic is working.

Comment: I think I'm with you, but now it doesn't stop moving until it reaches the top! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: if you look at the jsFiddle, you'll notice that I've also updated the `endTop` variable to 50. This is the amount of pixels it will stop from the top of the page - if you update that (try playing with the jsFiddle) you should be able to have it stop wherever you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead writing something from scratch consider using jQuery's [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method.